# Excel - search through range with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to basically do a `VLOOKUP`, but the content of my cell is too long for `VLOOKUP` to process. I therefore use this VBA script to search through a defined range:

```
Function betterSearch(searchCell, Range As String)

        For Each cell In Range
            If cell.Value = searchCell.Value Then
                    betterSearch = "Match"
                    Exit For
            End If
            betterSearch = "No match"
        Next

End Function
```

The function is called as (for example): `=betterSearch(B33;'Master'!C:C)`

However, I can't get a single output. I'm getting cross-eyed, what mistake am I making?

Comment: Shouldn't `Range as String` be `Range as Range`?

Comment: You variables should not have the same name as pre-existing methods.    `betterSearch(searchCell, Source As Range)`  would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm getting cross-eyed, what mistake am I making?*

Several.

- Parameter `Range` is declared as a `String`, but clearly used as if it were a `Range` object. It should be declared `As Range`.
- The name `Range` is hiding `Global.Range`, which may or may not be a problem (it isn't, *in this case*). Hiding/shadowing existing declarations in wider scopes is generally a bad idea.
- The function is implicitly `Public`. Better if explicitly so.
- Parameters are implicitly passed `ByRef`, but there's no justification for it; they should be passed `ByVal`.
- Parameter `searchCell` is an implicit `Variant`, but it's used as if it were a `Range` object; declare it `As Range`.
- Function returns an implicit `Variant`, but really returns a `String`. Signature should specify `As String` for the return type.
- Local variable `cell` isn't declared, which means it's an on-the-fly implicit `Variant`. Declare it explicitly, `As Range`.
- Code that compiles with undeclared variables doesn't have `Option Explicit` specified, which means VBA will happily compile and run any typo. Avoid stupid embarrassing problems, specify `Option Explicit` at the top of *every single module*, and *declare every single variable*.
- "No Match" return value is needlessly re-assigned on every iteration.
- Function name is `camelCase`, but public members in every single VBA type library are consistently `PascalCase`.
- Indentation isn't consistent.

[Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an open-source VBE add-in project I manage) would have picked up most of these points with its static code analysis.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function BetterSearch(ByVal searchCell As Range, ByVal source As Range) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In source
        If cell.Value = searchCell.Value Then
            BetterSearch = "Match"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    BetterSearch = "No match"
End Function
```

IMO the function would be much more useful if it returned a `Boolean` rather than a "magic string". `True` when found, `False` when not found.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand most of your comments, however, I run into the following oddity. If the Source Range is on the same worksheet as the searchCell, it works, but if the range is on a different worksheet, it returns a #VALUE! error?

Comment: Gah, typo / copy+paste error... should be `For Each cell In source` - fixed.

Comment: That one I caught ;) But it just wont work across worksheets?

Comment: hmm, it *should* work AFAICT. @Tampert replace `Exit For` with `Exit Function` - works on my machine =)

Comment: Hmm it does indeed when I try it for a simple digit, but doesn't seem to work on some more complex text.

Comment: Works! The range it was searching through had a few #VALUE! errors of its own... Thanks again!